# Actual and format argument differ in length

Tags: java, constructor

This code shows an actual and format arguments differ in length error for the constructor when the length and type of the given arguments are the same. This is the constructer

```
class OfficialRecipient extends Recipient{
   private String designation;

   public OfficialRecipient(String name, String email_address, String designation){
       super(name,email_address);
       this.designation=designation;
}
```

And this is where I create a new object.

```
 public void addOfficialRecipient(String name,String email_address,String designation){

     OfficialRecipient friend = new OfficialRecipient(name,email_address,designation);
 }
```

And it gives this error.

```
constructor OfficialRecipient in class OfficialRecipient cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: String,String,String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the cde you have shown. Are you sure that you used the same `OfficialRecipient` class in `addOfficialRecipient`?

Comment: Your three argument constructor is apparently not recognized by the client class. Maybe you need to replace the latest class to the client's classpath.

Comment: I used the same `OfficialRecipient ` in both places. How can I replace this class to the client's classpath.

Comment: I don't know if this is accidental in your post, but your OfficialRecipient class does not have a closing brace.

Comment: that's an accident